# img attribute, multiple bindings and evaluation not working

Tags: knockout.js

KO newbie.

I kinda have this working except that it doesn't quite work!

I want to show the image tag (visible) if the user is logged in (I am using KO with MVC 4 and Razor):

```
<img id="imgFavRestaurant" data-bind="attr: { style: { visibility: UserId > 0 ? 'visible' : 'hidden' }, src:FavoriteOutletImageUrl }" />
```

It shows me the right images when the user is logged in however when the user is not logged in, I still see the image tag (but an empty image as I am returning an empty string for the url):

```
 var userId = 0;
            @if (Site.Web.Helpers.UserContext.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                @:userId = @Site.Web.Helpers.UserContext.User.Id;
            }

            self.UserId = userId;

            self.FavoriteOutletImageUrl = ko.computed(function () 
            { 
                if (userId <= 0)
                {
                    return '';
                }
               return (data.IsUserFavoriteOutlet) ? '@Url.Content("~/Images/FavOutlet.png")' : '@Url.Content("~/Images/NonFavOutlet.png")';
            });
```

where am I going wrong? Why does it always show the image tag? 
Also, how do I bind multiple attributes in KO and HTML5?

thank you

Comment: Can you create a self contained example _without_ Razor? It's not contributing much here, just show where it's failing. For extra points, post a fiddle.

Comment: I just managed to fix it buddy. I had to do this: data-bind="style: { visibility: UserId > 0 ? 'visible' : 'hidden' }, attr: { src: FavoriteOutletImageUrl }

Comment: Although that will work, keep in mind that UserId isn't an observable, so if UserId changes, this won't update.  Also, look into the [visible](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/visible-binding.html) binding.

Answer (score 1):

First, UserId is a plain value and won't update the view unless something forces KO to re-evaluate the binding context that this image element is in.  UserId should really be an observable:

```
self.UserId = ko.observable(userId);
```

Because the other issue that arises by not doing this is that your FavoriteOutletImageUrl computed won't update because userId isn't an observable, therefore the computed won't care if its value changes.  Same with 'data.IsUserFavoriteOutlet'.  You'll constantly evaluate this variable and perhaps the user's favorite outlet changes.  This should be:

```
self.IsFavoriteOutlet = ko.observable(data.IsUserFavoriteOutlet);
```

So your computed would be:

```
self.FavoriteOutletImageUrl = ko.computed(function () { 
    if (self.UserId() <= 0) {
        return '';
    }

    return self.IsUserFavoriteOutlet()
        ? '@Url.Content("~/Images/FavOutlet.png")'
        : '@Url.Content("~/Images/NonFavOutlet.png")';
 });
```

Now if the UserId changes or the IsUserFavoriteOutlet changes, this computed will re-evaluate itself.

In your binding, use the KO `visible` binding instead to show/hide elements.

```
<img id="imgFavRestaurant" data-bind="visible: UserId > 0 ? 'visible' : 'hidden',
    attr: { src: FavoriteOutletImageUrl }" />
```

The other thing you should consider is making a computed property to bind with, instead of writing logic in your binding.

```
self.showRestaurantImage = ko.computed(function(){
    return self.userId() > 0;
});
```

and:

```
<img id="imgFavRestaurant" data-bind="visible: showRestaurantImage,
    attr: { src: FavoriteOutletImageUrl }" />
```

Comment: brilliant response Dennis. thank you. as you can tell, im very new to KO. I did try the visible data-bind but I always got an error thrown saying that the visible property was not found hence why I did the style thing instead. As it happens, the UserId won't change unless the user logs out in which case the page goes somewhere else however for better practice and "future" proof, your response is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this:

```
data-bind="style: { visibility: UserId > 0 ? 'visible' : 'hidden' }, attr: { src: FavoriteOutletImageUrl }
```